# Create Custom Qt Widget or Implement an existing widget?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qlistwidget, qtreewidget, custom-widgets

So I'm trying to work out how to design my wire-frame. It is essentially just two QScrollAreas, one above another, with a header (and button inside the header) for each.

Inside one design of the scroll area, I want to have items similar to a list of QListWidgetItems, however they would have a small image on the left side, and description on the right

On a another design of the scroll area, I would want just Rectangles filled with a color or pattern / image. They would all need to be selectable and emit a clicked signal.

Should I take the Class approach, and create a new class to act as a custom widget? Implement QWidget, and calculate where everything should be placed, changing background colors / opacities on mouse events, etc.?  Or is there another approach I should take to this? From what I've read, creating custom widgets is an absolute pain.

Below are wireframes of what I want to design - is there anything already available that would do the job? If not, how should I go about designing these? I thought about using a couple QListWidgets or QTreeWidgets, but they wouldn't accomplish everything I am looking for.

[image: Wireframes of custom "widgets"]

Comment: I just noticed the QItemDelegate - is this something I should be working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've chosen to instead take a different approach. Instead of a list or QScrollArea, I am just going to take a QGraphicsView and paint my own objects into it. I need it to handle a few more interactions (left and right clicks, tiny buttons inside it, etc.). I may implement it into a QListView when I understand it better, but for now, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may create your own QWidget based control. For the header part just drag a label and a button, for the rest, you may use a QListWidget or QListView with custom cells

Comment: Sorry, I can't say I'm an expert with Qt widgets yet - would you recommend just a new class based off a QWidget? And calculate orientations?

As for the QListView / QListWiget - any idea how to create custom cells with drastically different appearances than the default?